# Why is it my PHP Webservice cannot receive data from my Android device?

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

Both my laptop and my Android device is connected to the same WiFi. and I am trying to send data from my phone to the PHP webservice. But I can't get it work. What is the problem?

IP of my laptop: 192.168.0.10
IP of my phone: 192.168.0.9

I am listening from port80: ie:
            **HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.10:80");**

Following are the code of my PHP file:

```
<?php
$get = json_encode($_POST["req"]);
// Get data from object

$name = $get->req; // Get name you send
$age = $get->req; // Get age of user
?>
```

and below are my android code. Which part i'm doing wrongly? Please help!

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.10:80");

try {

    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();

    jsonobj.put("name", "Jensen");
    jsonobj.put("age", "22");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("req", jsonobj.toString()));

    Log.e("mainToPost", "mainToPost" + nameValuePairs.toString());

    // Use UrlEncodedFormEntity to send in proper format which we need
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Another thing, I have tried sending the data over too. I will need to press a button then the data will be passed. After I press the button, this is what I got (I'm connecting my phone through ADB):

[image: Android Monitor to my phone after I press the button.]

Comment: `$name = $get->req;` should be `$name = $get->name;`, same for age

Comment: Whats happen when you do
<?php
    print_r($_POST["req"]);

    echo "Success";
    }
    ?>

Comment: And `$get = json_encode($_POST["req"]);` should be `$get = json_decode($_POST["req"]);`

Comment: Are you able to access http://192.168.0.10:80 using your browser ?

Comment: Whats the name of your php script

Comment: @domos I have this line in my android code also
`responseServer = str.getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);`
`txt.setText(responseServer);`

then the response i get inside the textView in my phone shows: 
`Array( [req] =>{"age":"22","name":"Jensen"})Success`

but just one thing, my PHP webservice shown nothing. only showing errors "Notice: Undefined index: req in..." and "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...."

Comment: @IndraKumarS Yes I can access to my Webservice, with errors I replied above this comment. My php file name is **trySOAP1.php**. Ignore the name. Btw, I changed one line of my code to :

`HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.10:80/trySOAP1.php");`

Comment: @domos it shows **Array ( ) Success** in my google chrome laptop.

Comment: Post full php script

Comment: @domos the one i posted above in my code are my full PHP code. Is there anything I have missed? I haven't include connectDB.php yet because I cannot even get the data, so I dont want to involve database part first. What do you say?

Comment: That means you don't send it as `req` in post method, try 
 `<?php print_r($_POST); ` It will show you what you are receiving in POST method

Comment: @domos I shows **Array( )**. I am passing as an ArrayList.